# Scale of image with CSS3 animation

Tags: css, css-animations

I try to scale of image like light box. When run the size of image changed but with out animation.

```
<div id="dnn_ctr428_ContentPane" class="img-rectangular"><div id="dnn_ctr428_ModuleContent" class="DNNModuleContent ModDNNHTMLC">
    <div id="dnn_ctr428_HtmlModule_lblContent" class="Normal">
    <img alt="" src="/dnn_test/portals/0/Images/logo2.png?ver=1394-08-24-081741-293">
</div>

</div></div>
```

css:

```
.img-rectangular:hover img {

    width: 120%;
    height: 120%;
    -webkit-transition: width 2000ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:    width 2000ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:     width 2000ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:      width 2000ms ease-in-out;
    transition:         width 2000ms ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: *scale of image **with** css3 animation* and *size of image changed but **with out** animation.* - which of these is true?

Comment: I can't understand how both those are the same. Are you saying that your current code does it without animation whereas you want it to be done with animation?

Comment: Ok, but why do you need it specifically with animation? Transitions should be enough to scale the image on hover.

Comment: I want show an effect and this is beauty

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to scale the image while hovering on the container and it must be via an `animation` then you could use an animation with `transform: scale()` like in the below snippet.

Advantage of using `scale()` transforms as opposed to `width` and `height` change is that it **doesn't really require a set initial height and width**.

```css
/*.img-rectangular img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}*/
.img-rectangular:hover img {
  transform-origin: left top;
  animation: scale 2000ms ease-in-out forwards;
}
@keyframes scale {
  to {
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="dnn_ctr428_ContentPane" class="img-rectangular">
  <div id="dnn_ctr428_ModuleContent" class="DNNModuleContent ModDNNHTMLC">
    <div id="dnn_ctr428_HtmlModule_lblContent" class="Normal">
      <img alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/nature/1">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

---

However, `animation` is not really required for this one and it can be done with just `transition` also. The advantage of using `transition` as opposed to an `animation` would be that transitions by default produce the reverse (downscale) effect on hover out while animation would require a different keyframe setting to achieve it.

```css
.img-rectangular img{
  /*width: 200px;
  height: 200px;*/
  transition: transform 2000ms ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: left top;
}
.img-rectangular:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div id="dnn_ctr428_ContentPane" class="img-rectangular">
  <div id="dnn_ctr428_ModuleContent" class="DNNModuleContent ModDNNHTMLC">
    <div id="dnn_ctr428_HtmlModule_lblContent" class="Normal">
      <img alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/nature/1">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution :)

Answer (score 3):

When using transitions, you must set an initial value and an additional value which you want to transition to.

So it seems that the problem is that you have not set an initial value for the image width.

Try something like this:

```
img {
    width: 100%; /* initial value for width */
    transition: width 2s ease-in-out;
}

.img-rectangular:hover img {
    width: 120%; /* on hover transition to this value */ 
    height: 120%;    
}
```

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/avck6yac/)

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  transition: width 2s ease-in-out;
}
.img-rectangular:hover img {
  width: 120%;
  height: 120%;
}
```

```html
<div id="dnn_ctr428_ContentPane" class="img-rectangular">
  <div id="dnn_ctr428_ModuleContent" class="DNNModuleContent ModDNNHTMLC">
    <div id="dnn_ctr428_HtmlModule_lblContent" class="Normal">
      <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yup that's correct. Height and width transitions need an initial value (whereas scale like in my answer doesn't because the default scale is 1). Anyway, plus one for making that point which I missed in my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="image">

.image {
   width : 100%;
   height: 100%;
}

.image:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```