# Center aligned zoom in / out Image animation

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a navigation where I want to show image on mouse over at the same time the text should go down to the image.

**Expected Output:** For Image, the width & height animation should start with 0% to 100% on moue over and on mouse out width value should be decreased from 100% to 0% and animation should be aligned center horizontal inside the li 's.

I tried the following code **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bexn7acg/1/)**

```
  <ul id="sdt_menu1" class="sdt_menu1">
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="nav-link"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/130/cccccc/000000.jpg&text=Dummy+Image" alt=""/><span class="sdt_link1">Home</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="repository.html" class="nav-link"> <img src="http://dummyimage.com/130/cccccc/000000.jpg&text=Dummy+Image" alt=""/><span class="sdt_link1">Contact</span> 
    </a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

**What I got:** Now, I almost created zoom in i.e from width 0 to 100, but on mouse out, its just blank instead of width 100 to 0

Comment: Can I ask why you have `width` and `transform: scale()` transition? `transform: scale(0)` is almost equivalent to `width: 0` and `height: 0`. What is the end outcome you need for `width`? Is it `auto` or `100%` (they are different). Whatever it is, set it on the default rule itself and just `transform` on hover.

Comment: @Harry, I tried lot of solutions, forgot to remove scale animation, thanks for noting that

Comment: Actually scale is the best suited for this. I would suggest that one above `width` transition/

Comment: You can have a look at this thread for some info - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33854532/scale-of-image-with-css3-animation/33854668#33854668 (the first snippet an animation whereas you're looking for transition and so I'd suggest the second snippet for you. Reason for the suggestion is also explained there.)

Comment: Sure will go through the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't animate `auto` width (transitions can only animate across numerical values):

```
ul.sdt_menu1 li:hover img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    width: auto; /*remove this line*/
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px gray;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px gray;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px gray;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bexn7acg/2/)

Comment: It's about the animation going back from 100% width to 0% here, the animation with the `auto` width actually works (probably due to other reasons)

Comment: Have you actually checked the fiddle before downvoting?

Comment: There was a snippet here before that didn't work but I see that it does work in the actual fiddle appearently..

Comment: Thanks this is almost near to what I need, is it possible to fix height of the image and only width should get animated on mouse out and mouse over from center of li

Comment: Instead of animating all properties change to animate width only `transition: width 1s ease-in-out;`

Answer (score -2):

So essentially you want the image to replace the `li`?

If so adding `overflow: hidden;` to `ul.sdt_menu1 li{}`
Will solve your problem